# discord.js "interaction failed" when my code didn't "fail"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if(!interaction.isMessageComponent()) return // Ignore slash commands

    const message   = interaction.message
    const member    = interaction.member
    const user      = interaction.user

    if(interaction.componentType === 'BUTTON'){
      switch(interaction.customId){
        case "button1":
          message.edit(...)
        break
      }
    }
})
```

it edits the message, no errors in console, but discord says "interaction failed"

Comment: Could you send the whole contents of your file? I suspect that the interactionCreate event is in the message event  ( nested ) otherwise you cant edit message with just message.edit since you havent defined it

Comment: const message = .... i did define it

Comment: oh my bad, found your problem would add the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`MessageComponentInteraction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageComponentInteraction) class does not offer an [`edit`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit) method rather it is for an [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) itself! for editing interaction messages one may use [`MessageComponentInteraction#editReply`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageComponentInteraction?scrollTo=editReply) or [`MessageComponentInteraction#update`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageComponentInteraction?scrollTo=update) method(s), here is an example on how to use it in your case:

```js
    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if (!interaction.isMessageComponent()) return
    
        let message = interaction.message;
        let member = interaction.member;
        let user = interaction.user;
    
        if (interaction.componentType === 'BUTTON') {
            switch (interaction.customId) {
                case "btn1":
                    return message.editReply({
                        content: `abcd`
                    });
                    break
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

it turns out i need to replace `message.edit` with `interaction.update`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.